# tkcalendar: Change output configuration for DateEntry()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am using the tkcalendar module that I just downloaded and would like to change the ~result~ background color and position if possible.  The code I found on line is below;

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def example1():
    def print_sel():
        print(cal.selection_get())

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', locale='en_US',
                   cursor="hand1", year=2018, month=2, day=5)

    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()


def example2():

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    cal = Calendar(top, selectmode='none')
    date = cal.datetime.today() + cal.timedelta(days=2)
    cal.calevent_create(date, 'Hello World', 'message')
    cal.calevent_create(date, 'Reminder 2', 'reminder')
    cal.calevent_create(date + cal.timedelta(days=-2), 'Reminder 1', 'reminder')
    cal.calevent_create(date + cal.timedelta(days=3), 'Message', 'message')

    cal.tag_config('reminder', background='red', foreground='yellow')

    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Label(top, text="Hover over the events.").pack()


def example3():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2, year=2018)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)





root = tk.Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar', command=example1).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='Calendar with events', command=example2).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='DateEntry', command=example3).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This actually runs fine.  I see the main root window below;

[image: screenshot 1]

Now, when I select "DateEntry", once again everything is fine.  I get the calendar pop up and I can select a date.  But when I'm done selecting my date, I get the graphic below;

[image: screenshot 2]

I would like to change the background color on the date and center the 8/29/18 in the center.  I have not found any way to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.

~OldManEd

Answer (score 1):

`DateEntry` inherits from the `ttk.Entry` widget, so what you want can be done exactly the same way as with a `ttk.Entry`:

- The position of the text inside the entry is controlled by the `justify` option:

  ```
  dateentry.configure(justify='center')
  ```
- The color of the background can be changed via the `fieldbackground` option of a ttk style:

  ```
  style = ttk.Style(root)
  style.configure('my.DateEntry', fieldbackground='red')
  dateentry.configure(style='my.DateEntry')
  ```